# Jquery On() not working as expected

Tags: jquery, datatable

I am trying to use this row highlight function and it works when the page is loaded but when I use the pagination the function doesn't seem to stay on. The row no longer will highlight.

```
$("#json-table tbody tr").on("click", function(event){
    $(this).toggleClass('row_selected');
});
```

Comment: You aren't using the correct syntax for event delegation. http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Does your pagination insert a new table or rows in the existing table dynamically. If so you should be using the delegated version of .on().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$("#json-table").on("click", "tbody tr", function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('row_selected');
});
```

Because you reload the table, you have to bind the `on()` handler to something that won't be replaced, so use either `#json-table` if you only alter the children, or its parent if not.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using correct syntax for [**on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/), use like this:

```
$(document).on('click','#json-table tbody tr', function(event){
    $(this).toggleClass('row_selected');
});
```